# Spark job fails in yarn-cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark

My job runs perfectly in spark on the yarn-client mode , but fails on the yarn-cluster mode, stating the error "**File does not exist: hdfs://192.xxx.x.x:port/user/hduser/.sparkStaging/application_1442810383301_0016/pyspark.zip**".
Although it shows that it has uploaded the file to the above directory!!
What could be the cause??

This is the full error log:

```
 Application application_1449548654695_0003 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1449548654695_0003_000002 exited with exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://server1:8088/cluster/app/application_1449548654695_0003Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: File does not exist: hdfs://192.168.0.109:54310/user/hduser/.sparkStaging/application_1449548654695_0003/pyspark.zip
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://192.168.0.109:54310/user/hduser/.sparkStaging/application_1449548654695_0003/pyspark.zip
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1309)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:253)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:63)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:361)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:358)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:62)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the full error log?

Also did you set the master of the application to "yarn-cluster"? You can do it for python like so:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster("yarn-cluster")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Comment: I've added the log file as requested. Kindly see to it. @Ton Torres

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? How are you submitting the spark job?

Comment: I use the spark-submit script. 
./spark-submit --master yarn-cluster code.py

Comment: Yes, but in the actual code where you initialize the spark context you have to set the master to YARN-cluster.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the info, I'll try to do so in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by:

```
// i.e. remove the .setMaster("yarn-cluster")
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("hello-spark");
```

and the parameter for master passed in command line:

```
./bin/spark-submit --class path.to.your.Class --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster [options] <app jar> [app options]
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, add setting the Hadoop config files didn’t help:
`HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop`
`YARN_CONF_DIR =/etc/Hadoop`
Instead, the key was that `spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS` must be set in `SparkConf` inside Python.
Below is my code. Before I run it, I set my environment variables for the host of the resource manager and the HDFS file system.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

def test():
    print('Hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _app_name = "DemoApp"

    # I define these environment variables before calling
    # e.g., HADOOP_RM_HOST='myhost.edu'
    _rm_host = os.environ['HADOOP_RM_HOST']
    _fs_host = os.environ['HADOOP_FS_HOST']

    # It's written that these environment variables should be set, but don't do anything for my Python
    # Adding the core-site.xml, yarn-site.xml etc. to Python path doesn't do anything for my Python
    # HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop
    # YARN_CONF_DIR =/etc/hadoop

    # Run without Yarn, max threads
    local_conf = SparkConf().setAppName(_app_name) \
        .setMaster("local[*]")

    # If you have bad substitution error: https://medium.com/@o20021106/run-pyspark-on-yarn-c7cd04b87d81
    # There must be a hdfs://user/ID directory for the ID that this runs under (owned by ID)
    # https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dN60fkxABZs
    # spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS is required so that the files will be copied to the cluster
    # If the cluster doesn't dynamically allocate executors, then .set("spark.executor.instances", "4")
    yarn_conf = SparkConf().setAppName(_app_name) \
                    .setMaster("yarn") \
                    .set("spark.executor.memory", "4g") \
                    .set("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://{}:8020".format(_fs_host)) \
                    .set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.hostname", _rm_host)\
                    .set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address", "{}:8050".format(_rm_host))

    sc = SparkContext(conf=yarn_conf)

    test()
```