# Spark Python submission error : File does not exist: pyspark.zip

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm trying to submit python spark application on **yarn-cluster** mode.

```
Seq(System.getenv("SPARK_HOME")+"/bin/spark-submit","--master",sparkConfig.getString("spark.master"),"--executor-memory",sparkConfig.getString("spark.executor-memory"),"--num-executors",sparkConfig.getString("spark.num-executors"),"python/app.py") !
```

I'm getting following error ,

> Diagnostics: File does not exist:
>   hdfs://xxxxxx:8020/user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_123456789_0138/pyspark.zip
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist:
>   hdfs://xxxxxx:8020/user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_123456789_0138/pyspark.zip

I found https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10795

But the ticket is still open !

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you are trying to spark-submit a job with deploy-mode "cluster" and you are trying to set master as "local"; e.g.

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("spark-pi-app").setMaster("local[10]");
```

You have two options:
Option #1:
Change the above line to:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("spark-pi-app");
```

and submit your job as

```
./bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 512m --executor-memory 512m --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 3 --jars hadoop-common-{version}.jar,hadoop-lzo-{version}.jar --verbose --queue hadoop-queue --class "SparkPi" sparksbtproject_2.11-1.0.jar
```

Option #2: Submit your job with deploy-mode as "client"

```
./bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 512m --executor-memory 512m --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 3 --jars hadoop-common-{version}.jar,hadoop-lzo-{version}.jar --verbose --queue hadoop-queue --class "SparkPi" sparksbtproject_2.11-1.0.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

In my experience with scala jobs i have seen that the yarn-cluster cluster mode gives this error when the code is trying to setMaster("local") somewhere. 
Please try to remove any reference to setting a local "master".

Again, My answer is based on the scala behavior but hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you failing to create a proper spark context?  I suspect that is the issue.  I have also updated https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10795

Answer (score 0):

Try to add HDFS name node property to yarn-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://your-name-hode-host-port:8989</value>
</property>
```

Ensure that YARN_CONF_DIR env variable points to the directory of yarn-site.xml

Comment: That property doesn't exist in yarn-site. It's core-site

Answer (score 0):

I answered this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55457870/3357812. For me, the key was that spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS must be set in SparkConf inside Python.

```
yarn_conf = SparkConf().setAppName(_app_name) \
                    .setMaster("yarn") \
                    .set("spark.executor.memory", "4g") \
                    .set("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://{}:8020".format(_fs_host)) \
                    .set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.hostname", _rm_host)\
                    .set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address", "{}:8050".format(_rm_host))
```

Answer (score 0):

HADOOP_CONF_DIR variable must be set so spark can find this file.

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
```

> Set it in $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh