# when I use spark-submit to run my job.py,it always says the file 'pyspark.zip' does not exist

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Environment：spark-2.1

when I use spark-submit to run my job.py,it always says the file `pyspark.zip` does not exist.

I found this post : [Spark Python submission error : File does not exist: pyspark.zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632617/spark-python-submission-error-file-does-not-exist-pyspark-zip),

but it still can't work. My `run.sh` is as follow:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/lib/software/spark/spark-2.1/bin/spark-submit \
  --master yarn-cluster \
  --driver-memory 5G \
  --num-executors 12 \
  ./job.py
```

My `job.py` is as follow:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-  
import sys 
import os
from pyspark.ml.feature import Word2Vec
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import Row 
import jieba.posseg as posseg 
import jieba
if __name__ == "__main__":
    reload(sys)  
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
    sc = SparkContext(appName="fenci_0")
    date = '20180801' 
    scatelist = ['95']
    #compute 
    sc.stop()
```

I run the command: nohup ./run.sh >log 2>&1 &.

The log file is as follow:

```
nohup: 忽略输入
Warning: Master yarn-cluster is deprecated since 2.0. Please use master "yarn" with specified deploy mode instead.
18/08/21 15:29:28 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader main: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/08/21 15:29:29 INFO yarn.Client main: Requesting a new application from cluster with 2313 NodeManagers
18/08/21 15:29:29 INFO yarn.Client main: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (26624 MB per container)
18/08/21 15:29:29 INFO yarn.Client main: Will allocate AM container, with 5632 MB memory including 512 MB overhead
18/08/21 15:29:29 INFO yarn.Client main: Setting up container launch context for our AM
18/08/21 15:29:29 INFO yarn.Client main: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
18/08/21 15:29:29 INFO yarn.Client main: Preparing resources for our AM container
18/08/21 15:29:31 INFO yarn.Client main: Source and destination file systems are the same. Not copying viewfs://xxxx-cluster/home/spark/jar/spark-2.1.2-bin-U1/spark-2.1.2-bin-U1.zip
18/08/21 15:29:31 INFO yarn.Client main: Source and destination file systems are the same. Not copying viewfs://xxxx-cluster/home/spark/files/2.1/log4j.properties
18/08/21 15:29:31 INFO yarn.Client main: Uploading resource file:/home/job.py -> viewfs://xxxx-cluster/home/spark/stagingDir/.sparkStaging/application_1534831354007_17334/job.py
18/08/21 15:29:32 INFO yarn.Client main: Uploading resource file:/usr/lib/software/spark/spark-2.1/python/lib/pyspark.zip -> viewfs://xxxx-cluster/home/spark/stagingDir/.sparkStaging/application_1534831354007_17334/pyspark.zip
18/08/21 15:29:33 INFO yarn.Client main: Uploading resource file:/usr/lib/software/spark/spark-2.1/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip -> viewfs://xxxx-cluster/home/spark/stagingDir/.sparkStaging/application_1534831354007_17334/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip
18/08/21 15:29:33 INFO yarn.Client main: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-cae7c762-dc5e-4081-8b17-c1c136072780/__spark_conf__4062455229532468331.zip -> viewfs://xxxx-cluster/home/spark/stagingDir/.sparkStaging/application_1534831354007_17334/__spark_conf__.zip
18/08/21 15:29:34 INFO spark.SecurityManager main: Changing view acls to: hdp_lbg_ectech,dr.who
18/08/21 15:29:34 INFO spark.SecurityManager main: Changing modify acls to: hdp_lbg_ectech
18/08/21 15:29:34 INFO spark.SecurityManager main: Changing view acls groups to: 
18/08/21 15:29:34 INFO spark.SecurityManager main: Changing modify acls groups to: 
18/08/21 15:29:34 INFO spark.SecurityManager main: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(hdp_lbg_ectech, dr.who); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(hdp_lbg_ectech); groups with modify permissions: Set()
18/08/21 15:29:34 INFO yarn.Client main: Submitting application application_1534831354007_17334 to ResourceManager
18/08/21 15:29:34 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl main: Submitted application application_1534831354007_17334
18/08/21 15:29:35 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: SUBMITTED)
18/08/21 15:29:35 INFO yarn.Client main: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: root.spark.hdp_lbg_ectech.spark
     start time: 1534836574582
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://xxxxxxxxxxx:9088/proxy/application_1534831354007_17334/
     user: hdp_lbg_ectech
18/08/21 15:29:36 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: SUBMITTED)
18/08/21 15:29:37 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: SUBMITTED)
18/08/21 15:29:38 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: SUBMITTED)
18/08/21 15:29:39 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: SUBMITTED)
18/08/21 15:29:40 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:29:40 INFO yarn.Client main: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: root.spark.hdp_lbg_ectech.spark
     start time: 1534836574582
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://xxxxxxxxxxx:9088/proxy/application_1534831354007_17334/
     user: hdp_lbg_ectech
18/08/21 15:29:41 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:29:42 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:29:43 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:29:44 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:29:45 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:29:46 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:29:47 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:29:48 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:29:49 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:29:50 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:29:51 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:29:52 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:29:53 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:29:54 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:29:55 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:29:56 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:29:57 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:29:58 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:29:59 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:00 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:01 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:02 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:03 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:04 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:05 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:06 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:07 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:08 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:09 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:10 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:11 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:12 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:13 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:14 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:15 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:16 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:17 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:18 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:19 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:20 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:21 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:22 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:23 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:24 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:25 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:26 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:27 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:28 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:29 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:30 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:31 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:32 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:33 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:34 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:35 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:36 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:37 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:38 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:39 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:40 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:41 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:42 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:43 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:44 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:45 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:46 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:47 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:48 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:49 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:50 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:51 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:52 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:53 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:54 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:55 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:56 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:57 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:58 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:30:59 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:00 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:01 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:02 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:03 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:04 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:05 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:06 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:07 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:08 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:09 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:10 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:11 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:12 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:13 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:14 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:15 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:16 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:17 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:18 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:19 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:20 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:21 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:22 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:23 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:24 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:25 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:26 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:27 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:28 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:29 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:30 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:31 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:32 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:33 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:34 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:35 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:36 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:37 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:38 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:39 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:40 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:41 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:42 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:43 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:44 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:45 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:46 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:47 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:48 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:49 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:50 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:57 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:58 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:31:59 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:00 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:02 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:03 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:04 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:05 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:06 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:07 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:08 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:09 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:10 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:11 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:12 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:13 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:14 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:15 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:16 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:17 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:18 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:19 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:20 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:21 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: ACCEPTED)
18/08/21 15:32:22 INFO yarn.Client main: Application report for application_1534831354007_17334 (state: FAILED)
18/08/21 15:32:22 INFO yarn.Client main: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Application application_1534831354007_17334 failed 4 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1534831354007_17334_000004 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://xxxxxxxxxxx:9088/proxy/application_1534831354007_17334/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: File does not exist: hdfs://xxxx:8020/home/spark/stagingDir/.sparkStaging/application_1534831354007_17334/pyspark.zip
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://xxxx:8020/home/spark/stagingDir/.sparkStaging/application_1534831354007_17334/pyspark.zip
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:357)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: root.spark.hdp_lbg_ectech.spark
     start time: 1534836574582
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: http://xxxxxx:9088/cluster/app/application_1534831354007_17334
     user: hdp_lbg_ectech
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1534831354007_17334 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1231)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:744)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
18/08/21 15:32:22 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager Thread-3: Shutdown hook called
18/08/21 15:32:22 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager Thread-3: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-cae7c762-dc5e-4081-8b17-c1c136072780
```

Most post said the reason "`pyspark.zip` file does not exist" is the code somewhere set the master as `local`.But I can't find anywhere set the master as `local`,in my `run.sh`, I set the `yarn-cluster`."

Would you help me to solve this problem ? Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find my error.Beacause the log is running status.We should only look up the running status for some easy reason.To find a detail reason for the failed status,we should find the stdout log for the application_***************.
Finally I find in my code compute part.I uses collect(),it caused memory overflow.When I del the collect().It worked.
Sorry for not show my compute part code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `--master yarn-cluster` which is deprecated, as the log you posted says on the first line. This could be the cause of your problem, but I'm not sure. Try changing your shell script to:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/lib/software/spark/spark-2.1/bin/spark-submit \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --driver-memory 5G \
  --num-executors 12 \
  ./job.py
```

See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/submitting-applications.html

Alternatively, you could try to run your application in client mode. The driver will then run on the local machine (where you run `spark-submit` from), but the executors will run on YARN worker nodes. This is done using `--deploy-mode client`. This will likely solve your error, but you might have a specific reason to run the driver on a YARN node.

Comment: I tried to change the shell script with "--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster" but it still got the same error.The reason I run spark job with cluster mode is that the local machine is company's server which is limited in resources.When I run the job with client mode,it run successfully.

Comment: Thank you very much.My question is so long that you are so kind to read completely.

Comment: @LuckyNing the only other thing I can think of is that the user that is running the Spark application does not have the correct permissions to open pyspark.zip on the temporary location on HDFS. Did you check the location where YARN uploads the file?
 `hdfs://xxxx:8020/home/spark/stagingDir/.sparkStaging/application_1534831354007_17334/pyspark.zip`

Comment: sorry for late reply.I don't find 
`hdfs://xxxx:8020/home/spark/stagingDir/.sparkStaging/application_1534831354007_17334/pyspark.zip`,not even the directory.In order to exclude the time is too long that the `application_1534831354007_17334` is deleted,I run the run.sh again,the same error.I try to use `hadoop fs -ls` to check the application_xxxx directory,but there is no the directory.But the log says `Uploading resource file:/usr/lib/software/spark/spark-2.1/python/lib/pyspark.zip -> viewfs://xxxx-cluster/home/spark/stagingDir/.sparkStaging/application_xxxx/pyspark.zip`.